# hardlink multiple file to one file

Tags: c++, linux, shell

I have many files in a folder. I want to concatenate all these files to a single file. For example cat * > final_file;
But this will increase disk space. Is there is a way where I can hardlink all the files to final_file? For example ln * final_file.

Comment: This question might be better served on [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix.SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) as it's not really relevant to programming.

Comment: What does this have to do with either C++ or shell programming?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible using links.

If you really need this kind of feature and can not afford to create one large file you could go for a custom file system driver. FUSE will allow you to write a simple file system driver which runs in the user space and allows to access the files as they were one large file.

You could also write a custom block device (e.g. by emulating the NBD "Network Block Device" protocol) which combines two or more files into one large block device.

Getting to know the concrete use case would help to give a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

No. Hardlinking links 2 files, nothing more. The filesystem does not support that at an underlying level.